# how to call usequery again react query

Tags: react-query

hey i have a query that fetch all the posts in my site and i want that when im creating a new post this query will run again and i will see the new post

````
    const res = await apiService.get.GET_ALLPOSTS(pageParam);
    return res;
  };
  const {
    data,
    error,
    fetchNextPage,
    hasNextPage,
    isFetching,
    isFetchingNextPage,
    status,
  } = useInfiniteQuery(["posts"], fetchPosts, {
    getNextPageParam: (_lastPage, pages) => {
      if (!pages[pages.length - 1].data[0]) {
        return undefined;
      } else {
        return pages.length + 1;
      }
    },
  });```
````

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to invalidate your query.

Specifically

```js
const queryClient = useQueryClient();
queryClient.invalidateQueries(["posts"]);
```

Assuming you are using a `useMutation` hook to create your new post you can just call that second line in the `onSuccess` handler for the mutation hook.